# Fastest screencopy on windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, screen-capture

Currently, I am working on screenshotting the screen and copying it to my application.

```
static bool first = false;
static IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
static IDirect3DSurface9* pBackbuffer;

HRESULT hr;
if (first == false)
{
    hr = m_pD3DDevice9Ex->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(1920, 1080,
        D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pSurface, NULL);
    hr = m_pD3DDevice9Ex->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackbuffer);
    first = true;
}

if (pSurface != NULL)
{
    hr = m_pD3DDevice9Ex->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
    hr = m_pD3DDevice9Ex->UpdateSurface(pSurface, NULL, pBackbuffer, NULL);
}
```

code works, but It is extremely slow (60-80fps on 1920x1080).

I want to do a screen capture that guarantees at least 144hz. What can I do?

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, the logic of the variable `first` seems opposite of what it should be. It would make more sense if it was *true* for the **first** time. Otherwise, rename it as `not_first`?

Comment: "Extremely Slow" - 80 fps is already 4 Gbps. The reason why we can achieve 1920x1080x144 today is by **not** processing frames in C++ at that rate; we leave it to the GPU.

Comment: @MSalters If so, is there any way to process screen copy on a GPU basis?

Comment: @medq: Well, presumably you want to do more with the screen than just copy it. Modern GPU's often have options to compress the screen in real time to a H.264/5 stream, but that's rather specific to those GPU's. (it's typically hardware-accelerated, using custom GPU hardware). But we can't guess what you want to do with it.

Comment: @MSalters All I'm trying to do is put a desktop screen on my application and add some subtitles. And I don't need scaling, and I maintain the original resolution.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually need the pixels themselves. You just want to have the system draw them in your window, and then you want to compose additional content on top. A DWM thumbnail might do the trick. (Set the thumbnail size = actual size to make it a "full size thumbnail"). Another option is to use [the screen capture API](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/).